# How to change value of multiple iterated element in ejs dynamically?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, ejs, viewengine

Here is my EJS code:
when I click on any iterated button it only changes first element's value. But I want to make other element to change as well. What's wrong with it?

```
<% for(let i=0; i<10; i++){
    %> <h2 id="value">0</h2>  <button onclick="btnHandler()">click to change</button> </h1> <%
} %>

<script> 
    let val = document.getElementById('value');
    let start = 0
    function btnHandler(){
        val.innerHTML = `${start++}`
    }
</script>
```

I try to to change value of iterated element using iterated button with onlclick but it only affect first elements.
I expect to change other element as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the rendered HTML, you have 10 `<h2>` elements and 10 `<button>`s, but there is no correspondence between each `<button>` and "its" `<h2>` element. Moreover, all the `<h2>` elements have the same `id`, and you have only one `start` counter whereas you need 10.

The following solution relates `<h2>` elements, `<button>`s and counters by the index `i`. I assume this is what you intend to achieve.

```
<% for(let i=0; i<10; i++){
    %> <h2 id="value-<%= i %>">0</h2>  <button onclick="btnHandler(<%= i %>)">click to change</button> <%
} %>
<script> 
let start = [];
function btnHandler(i){
  start[i] = start[i] || 0;
  let val = document.getElementById('value-' + i);
  val.innerHTML = ++start[i];
}
</script>
```